# how to display Google Form in other languages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, kannada

I want to create google form to display it in the Kannada language. I have tried it using [how to display form in particular langauge](http://socialsignal.com/blog/rob-cottingham/how-display-a-google-form-a-particular-language)
but this is not helping me while I have an embed form link to my website.
Need some help to fix this issue

Here Is my Embedded Script: `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScmizOg7rqWhqand5kfRuPysqAjdf9LZb9VAyfP6PzaUlo2uQ/viewform?**&hl=kn**embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>`

Comment: Can you describe what is happening or better yet create a public document so we can see for ourselves?

Comment: Add the embedding code that you tried.

Comment: here is my embedding code: <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScmizOg7rqWhqand5kfRuPysqAjdf9LZb9VAyfP6PzaUlo2uQ/viewform?&hl=knembedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>

Comment: From my end it is displaying Chinese. I think now Google auto detects the viewer's language.